# How to set up a Node.js project with node-java as Java API bridge and node-java-maven to manage the Java dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-java

I'm trying to initialize a Java instance for a `Node.js` project. I want to use this project to manage the dependencies:

https://github.com/joeferner/node-java-maven

and this project as the Java API bridge:

https://github.com/joeferner/node-java

I am using ES6 and I created a class with a static method to initialize and return a Java instance. I don't understand the usage example on the `node-java-maven` project page. I have taken their code and copied it into my static initialization method, but the `mvn` function doesn't appear to execute. I'm really new to Javascript and Node.js, so I don't know how to invoke the code that actually adds all the dependencies from the maven results to the classpath. All the jar files in the 'resources' folder are added. I just can't figure out how to use `node-java-maven` to add the dependencies I specified in my `package.json` file.

My environment:

```
Mac OSX, El Capitan
ES6 Javascript
Java version:
    java version "1.8.0_131"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

My class is here:

```
export class JavaInit {

    static getJavaInstance() {
        let fs = require("fs");
        let java = require("java");
        let mvn = require('node-java-maven');

        let baseDir = "./resources";
        let dependencies = fs.readdirSync(baseDir);

        dependencies.forEach(function(dependency){
            java.classpath.push(baseDir + "/" + dependency);
        });

        java.classpath.push("./target/classes");
        java.classpath.push("./target/test-classes");

        //Nothing happens here. I set a breakpoint, and nothing inside the brackets executes.
        mvn((err, mvnResults) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.error('could not resolve maven dependencies', err);
            }
            //This line is never printed to the console when I call the 
            //getJavaInstance() method
            console.log("DID THIS EXECUTE");
            mvnResults.classpath.forEach(function(c) {
                //There are no lines output to the console indicating that
                //dependencies were added to the classpath
                console.log('adding ' + c + ' to classpath');
                java.classpath.push(c);
            });

            let Version = java.import('org.apache.lucene.util.Version');
        });

        return java;
    }

}
```

Here is a copy of the test method I wrote and executed:

```
import {JavaInit} from "../JavaInit"

describe("Test", () => {
    it("Load Java",()=>{
        JavaInit.getJavaInstance();
    });
});
```

When I run this test method, the output is this:

```
[13:48:05] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[13:48:05] I/local - Starting selenium standalone server...
[13:48:06] I/local - Selenium standalone server started at http://192.168.2.7:63176/wd/hub
Started

2 specs, 0 failures
Finished in 0.274 seconds

resolving parent: org.apache.lucene:lucene-parent:4.9.0
resolving parent: org.apache.lucene:lucene-solr-grandparent:4.9.0
resolving parent: org.apache:apache:13
[13:48:08] I/local - Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[13:48:08] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[13:48:08] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Here is a copy of my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "testsuite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "testsuite",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor conf.js",
    "start_selenium": "node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/bin/webdriver-manager start",
    "update_selenium": "node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/bin/webdriver-manager update"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "install": "^0.10.1",
    "jasmine": "^2.6.0",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.1",
    "java": "^0.8.0",
    "node-java-maven": "0.0.12",
    "npm": "^5.0.4",
    "protractor": "^5.1.2"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "es6"
  ],
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015"
    ]
  },
  "java": {
    "exclusions": [
      {
        "groupId": "xml-apis",
        "artifactId": "xml-apis"
      }
    ],
    "dependencies": [
      {
        "groupId": "org.apache.lucene",
        "artifactId": "lucene-core",
        "version": "4.9.0"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "com.google.code.findbugs",
        "artifactId": "jsr305",
        "version": "3.0.2"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "com.google.code.findbugs",
        "artifactId": "findbugs",
        "version": "3.0.1"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "com.google.code.findbugs",
        "artifactId": "annotations",
        "version": "3.0.1"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "org.slf4j",
        "artifactId": "slf4j-ext",
        "version": "1.7.12"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "org.slf4j",
        "artifactId": "slf4j-api",
        "version": "1.7.12"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "ch.qos.logback",
        "artifactId": "logback-core",
        "version": "1.1.3"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "ch.qos.logback",
        "artifactId": "logback-classic",
        "version": "1.1.3"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "org.testng",
        "artifactId": "testng",
        "version": "6.9.9"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "org.projectlombok",
        "artifactId": "lombok",
        "version": "1.16.6"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "org.apache.commons",
        "artifactId": "commons-lang3",
        "version": "3.4"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "org.apache.commons",
        "artifactId": "commons-collections4",
        "version": "4.0"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "com.fasterxml.jackson.core",
        "artifactId": "jackson-core",
        "version": "2.9.0.pr2"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "com.fasterxml.jackson.core",
        "artifactId": "jackson-databind",
        "version": "2.9.0.pr2"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "com.fasterxml.jackson.core",
        "artifactId": "jackson-annotations",
        "version": "2.9.0.pr2"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype",
        "artifactId": "jackson-datatype-jdk8",
        "version": "2.9.0.pr2"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype",
        "artifactId": "jackson-datatype-joda",
        "version": "2.9.0.pr2"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "org.eclipse.persistence",
        "artifactId": "org.eclipse.persistence.moxy",
        "version": "2.6.3"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "javax.xml.bind",
        "artifactId": "jaxb-api",
        "version": "2.2.12"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "org.codehaus.groovy",
        "artifactId": "groovy-all",
        "version": "2.4.7"
      },
      {
        "groupId": "joda-time",
        "artifactId": "joda-time",
        "version": "2.9.4"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I run this script before attempting to execute the test class, this is the output:

```
sephilli$ ./node_modules/.bin/node-java-maven 

resolving: org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:4.9.0
resolving parent: org.apache.lucene:lucene-parent:4.9.0
resolving parent: org.apache.lucene:lucene-solr-grandparent:4.9.0
resolving parent: org.apache:apache:13
resolving: org.apache.lucene:lucene-parent:4.9.0
resolving parent: org.apache.lucene:lucene-solr-grandparent:4.9.0
resolving parent: org.apache:apache:13
resolving: org.apache.lucene:lucene-solr-grandparent:4.9.0
resolving parent: org.apache:apache:13
resolving: org.apache:apache:13
resolving: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2
resolving parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:7
resolving: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:7
resolving: com.google.code.findbugs:findbugs:3.0.1
resolving parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:7
resolving: com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1
resolving parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:7
resolving: org.slf4j:slf4j-ext:1.7.12
resolving parent: org.slf4j:slf4j-parent:1.7.12
resolving: org.slf4j:slf4j-parent:1.7.12
resolving: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12
resolving parent: org.slf4j:slf4j-parent:1.7.12
resolving: ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.3
resolving parent: ch.qos.logback:logback-parent:1.1.3
resolving: ch.qos.logback:logback-parent:1.1.3
resolving: ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.3
resolving parent: ch.qos.logback:logback-parent:1.1.3
resolving: org.testng:testng:6.9.9
resolving: org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.6
resolving: org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4
resolving parent: org.apache.commons:commons-parent:37
resolving parent: org.apache:apache:16
resolving: org.apache.commons:commons-parent:37
resolving parent: org.apache:apache:16
resolving: org.apache:apache:16
resolving: org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.0
resolving parent: org.apache.commons:commons-parent:32
resolving parent: org.apache:apache:13
resolving: org.apache.commons:commons-parent:32
resolving parent: org.apache:apache:13
resolving: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.0.pr2
resolving parent: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-parent:2.9.pr1b
resolving parent: com.fasterxml:oss-parent:28
resolving: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-parent:2.9.pr1b
resolving parent: com.fasterxml:oss-parent:28
resolving: com.fasterxml:oss-parent:28
resolving: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.0.pr2
resolving parent: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.9.0.pr2
resolving parent: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-parent:2.9.pr1b
resolving parent: com.fasterxml:oss-parent:28
resolving: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.9.0.pr2
resolving parent: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-parent:2.9.pr1b
resolving parent: com.fasterxml:oss-parent:28
resolving: com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0.pr2
resolving parent: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-parent:2.9.pr1b
resolving parent: com.fasterxml:oss-parent:28
resolving: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.9.0.pr2
resolving parent: com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-modules-java8:2.9.0.pr2
resolving parent: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.9.0.pr2
resolving parent: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-parent:2.9.pr1b
resolving parent: com.fasterxml:oss-parent:28
resolving: com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-modules-java8:2.9.0.pr2
resolving parent: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.9.0.pr2
resolving parent: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-parent:2.9.pr1b
resolving parent: com.fasterxml:oss-parent:28
resolving: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda:2.9.0.pr2
resolving parent: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.9.0.pr2
resolving parent: com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-parent:2.9.pr1b
resolving parent: com.fasterxml:oss-parent:28
resolving: org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.moxy:2.6.3
resolving: javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12
resolving parent: net.java:jvnet-parent:4
resolving: net.java:jvnet-parent:4
resolving: org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7
resolving: joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4
resolving: net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0
resolving: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
resolving: com.google.code.findbugs:bcel-findbugs:6.0
resolving: com.google.code.findbugs:jFormatString:2.0.1
resolving: dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
resolving: org.apache.ant:ant:1.7.1
resolving parent: org.apache.ant:ant-parent:1.7.1
resolving: org.apache.ant:ant-parent:1.7.1
resolving: org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.2
resolving parent: org.ow2.asm:asm-parent:5.0.2
resolving parent: org.ow2:ow2:1.3
resolving: org.ow2.asm:asm-parent:5.0.2
resolving parent: org.ow2:ow2:1.3
resolving: org.ow2:ow2:1.3
resolving: org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:5.0.2
resolving parent: org.ow2.asm:asm-parent:5.0.2
resolving parent: org.ow2:ow2:1.3
resolving: commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
resolving parent: org.apache.commons:commons-parent:17
resolving parent: org.apache:apache:7
resolving: org.apache.commons:commons-parent:17
resolving parent: org.apache:apache:7
resolving: org.apache:apache:7
resolving: com.apple:AppleJavaExtensions:1.4
resolving: jaxen:jaxen:1.1.6
resolving parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:7
resolving: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1
resolving parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:7
resolving: ch.qos.cal10n:cal10n-api:0.8.1
resolving parent: ch.qos.cal10n:cal10n-parent:0.8.1
resolving: ch.qos.cal10n:cal10n-parent:0.8.1
resolving: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7
resolving parent: org.slf4j:slf4j-parent:1.7.7
resolving: org.slf4j:slf4j-parent:1.7.7
resolving: junit:junit:4.10
resolving: com.beust:jcommander:1.48
resolving parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:3
resolving: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:3
resolving: org.apache.ant:ant:1.7.0
resolving parent: org.apache.ant:ant-parent:1.7.0
resolving: org.apache.ant:ant-parent:1.7.0
resolving: com.google.inject:guice:4.0
resolving parent: com.google.inject:guice-parent:4.0
resolving parent: com.google:google:5
resolving: com.google.inject:guice-parent:4.0
resolving parent: com.google:google:5
resolving: com.google:google:5
resolving: org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.15
resolving: org.beanshell:bsh:2.0b4
resolving parent: org.beanshell:beanshell:2.0b4
resolving: org.beanshell:beanshell:2.0b4
resolving: joda-time:joda-time:2.7
resolving: org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.core:2.6.3
resolving: javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
resolving: org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4
resolving parent: org.glassfish:json:1.0.4
resolving parent: net.java:jvnet-parent:3
resolving: org.glassfish:json:1.0.4
resolving parent: net.java:jvnet-parent:3
resolving: net.java:jvnet-parent:3
resolving: xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2
resolving: org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.7.1
resolving parent: org.apache.ant:ant-parent:1.7.1
resolving: org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:5.0.2
resolving parent: org.ow2.asm:asm-parent:5.0.2
resolving parent: org.ow2:ow2:1.3
resolving: xml-apis:xml-apis:1.3.02
resolving: xerces:xercesImpl:2.6.2
resolving: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1
resolving parent: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent:1.1
resolving: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-parent:1.1
resolving: org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.7.0
resolving parent: org.apache.ant:ant-parent:1.7.0
resolving: javax.inject:javax.inject:1
resolving: aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
resolving: com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1
resolving parent: com.google.guava:guava-parent:16.0.1
resolving parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:7
resolving: com.google.guava:guava-parent:16.0.1
resolving parent: org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:7
resolving: org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.asm:2.6.3
resolving: org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.2
resolving parent: org.ow2.asm:asm-parent:5.0.2
resolving parent: org.ow2:ow2:1.3
resolving: jmock:jmock:1.1.0
resolving: junit:junit:4.0
resolving: org.easymock:easymock:2.2
resolving: junit:junit:3.8.1
COMPLETE
[ '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/apache/lucene/lucene-core/4.9.0/lucene-core-4.9.0.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.2/jsr305-3.0.2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/findbugs/3.0.1/findbugs-3.0.1.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/annotations/3.0.1/annotations-3.0.1.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-ext/1.7.12/slf4j-ext-1.7.12.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.12/slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.3/logback-core-1.1.3.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.3/logback-classic-1.1.3.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/testng/testng/6.9.9/testng-6.9.9.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/projectlombok/lombok/1.16.6/lombok-1.16.6.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.4/commons-lang3-3.4.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-collections4/4.0/commons-collections4-4.0.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.0.pr2/jackson-core-2.9.0.pr2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.0.pr2/jackson-databind-2.9.0.pr2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0.pr2/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.pr2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.0.pr2/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.0.pr2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-joda/2.9.0.pr2/jackson-datatype-joda-2.9.0.pr2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy/2.6.3/org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.6.3.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.12/jaxb-api-2.2.12.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.4.7/groovy-all-2.4.7.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.9.4/joda-time-2.9.4.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/net/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.1/jsr305-2.0.1.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/bcel-findbugs/6.0/bcel-findbugs-6.0.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jFormatString/2.0.1/jFormatString-2.0.1.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.7.1/ant-1.7.1.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-debug-all/5.0.2/asm-debug-all-5.0.2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-commons/5.0.2/asm-commons-5.0.2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/apple/AppleJavaExtensions/1.4/AppleJavaExtensions-1.4.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/jaxen/jaxen/1.1.6/jaxen-1.1.6.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.1/jsr305-3.0.1.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/ch/qos/cal10n/cal10n-api/0.8.1/cal10n-api-0.8.1.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.10/junit-4.10.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/beust/jcommander/1.48/jcommander-1.48.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant/1.7.0/ant-1.7.0.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/google/inject/guice/4.0/guice-4.0.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.15/snakeyaml-1.15.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/beanshell/bsh/2.0b4/bsh-2.0b4.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.7/joda-time-2.7.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.core/2.6.3/org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.6.3.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/javax.json/1.0.4/javax.json-1.0.4.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.7.1/ant-launcher-1.7.1.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm-tree/5.0.2/asm-tree-5.0.2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.02/xml-apis-1.3.02.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/xerces/xercesImpl/2.6.2/xercesImpl-2.6.2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.1/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.7.0/ant-launcher-1.7.0.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/16.0.1/guava-16.0.1.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/persistence/org.eclipse.persistence.asm/2.6.3/org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.6.3.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/ow2/asm/asm/5.0.2/asm-5.0.2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/jmock/jmock/1.1.0/jmock-1.1.0.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.0/junit-4.0.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/org/easymock/easymock/2.2/easymock-2.2.jar',
  '/Users/sephilli/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar' ]
```

Comment: Did you run `./node_modules/.bin/node-java-maven`?

Comment: Yes. I did that before trying to execute the test code.

Comment: @joegtp I updated the question with more details: I added source code for the test method that calls the `getJavaInstance()` method and the output I get when I run it. I added the `package.json` file for my project and the output I get when I run `./mode_modules/.bin/node-java-maven`.

Comment: @joegtp I also added details about my execution environment.